# XSLT namespace incorrect

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Hi I currently have the following namespace in my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="products.xsl"?>
<products xmlns="http://localhost" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://localhost products.xsd">
    <product>
         <productname>Product 1</productname>
         <productname>Product 2</productname>
         <productname>Product 3</productname>
         <productdetails>Details go here</productdetails>
         .... other elements that I don't use....
    </product>
</products>
```

When I try to run my XSL file I don't get any product names, I can get the product names i I remove the namespaces in product root element. So my namespaces mys be wrong. Can someone tell me where I've gone wrong? 
My xsl files is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"
    doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <!--  HTML page starts here  -->
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Products Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2>Products</h2>
            <ul>
                <xsl:for-each select="products/product/productname">
                    <li>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </li>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
    <!--  HTML page ends here  -->
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The results I am looking for is

```
...(the other XHTML tags)...
<ul>
    <li>Product 1</li>
    <li>Product 2</li>
    <li>Product 3</li>
</ul>
...(rest of XHTML tags)..
```

But I'm not getting that at all, all I get is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>Products Page</title>
   </head>
 <body>
   <h2>Products</h2>
     <ul></ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see there is no products showing?

Comment: Why `output method="xml"` when you seem to want to output HTML? And which result do you want? Your `product` has several `productname` child elements so I would think you want to use `<xsl:for-each select="x:products/x:product/x:productname">`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen The XML output method is typically used for XHTML.

Comment: Yes I want XHTML output, and I have amended the code to show that there are more elements, I just want to display the products or list all the products. The rest I don't want. I am not getting any results from the above. Hence the reason I used `<xsl:value-of select="x:productname"/>` instead of what you suggested as I don't want all the other elements.

Comment: If you want to create XHTML then you need to make sure you put your result elements into the XHTML namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` with `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ..>`, otherwise your elements are not recognized as XHTML. It certainly does not makes sense to use output method `xml` to output XHTML but have result elements in no namespace.

Comment: OK So I got that wrong too. I am learning here so bear with me, you say I have to change `xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` with `xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`? Would it be better to do it in HTML5?

Comment: No, the XSLT namespace is correct, but if you want to output XHTML then you need to have `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">`. I would certainly these days recommend to simply generate HTML and use output method `html`, in particular with XSLT 1.0 run within the browser.

Comment: Ah I see, so rather than have xml I should have html and the rest stays the same? `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:x="http://localhost" exclude-result-prefixes="x">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"
    doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>` For HTML5 do I need to use `doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"` because I have noticed without it the results doesn't display `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem, when I use http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2014031601.xml and http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2014031601.xsl or http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2014031602.xml and http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2014031601.xsl, Firefox and IE show a product name.

Comment: Martin what happens when you include the xsd file? When I delete the `xmlns:x="http://localhost" exclude-result-prefixes="x">` line it works, but then I must delete the whole `xmlns="http://localhost" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://localhost products.xsd"` from the products element and it will work. But with it in here, it doesn't show. I don't get that result you get.

Comment: I have the following namespaces in the schema `<xs:schema version="1.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://example.com/products"
           xmlns="http://example.com/products"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">` Then I have the following on the products root element in the xml `<products   xmlns="http://example.com/products" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/products products.xsd">` Could it be those that are not giving me the same results?

Comment: Do the samples I posted render in your browser as wanted, with a product name? If not tell us exactly which browser you use. If those samples work as wanted, then post a link to your sample that does not work or at least edit your question with minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem. As for the schema, I don't see how it is relevant to XSLT. The namespaces matter but whether you provide a schema or not for your XML does not matter, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Well the sample you posted and that I used only has one `x:products/x:product` element.

Comment: Yes thanks Martin, I got it working without the namespaces `xmlns="http://example.com/products" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/products products.xsd` in the product element, so not sure why mine don't work, the ones you posted work, but if I add in the namespace then it doesn't work. So now I am know the problem lies in the namespaces. I have amended the sample code above to what I was looking for. It seems to not work but if I delete the namespace and only have **<product>** it works.

Comment: Your latest edit has an XML input with elements in the default namespace `http://localhost`, yet your XSLT tries to address elements `products/product/productname` in no namespace. That is never going to work, you will need to follow the approach in http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2014031601.xsl i.e. to declare `xmlns:x="http://localhost"` in the XSLT and to use e.g. `x:products/x:product/x:productname` in the path expressions or match patterns in your XSLT to select or match elements from the input XML.

Comment: I see, I think I understand and I do get the correct results when I add the prefix to as you stated above.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, XPath (and therefore XSLT) is namespace-aware, but (in the 1.0 version of these standards at least) does not have the concept of default namespace (xmlns=) assignment. If you want to select namespaced nodes, your XPath *must* use explicit prefixes bound to the correct namespaces.

Comment: Thanks Wanted to tick this green as both you and Martin helped me understand the problem.